# Error tipográfico en privilegio de "Editar Preguntas Y Respuestas"

Tags: soporte, estado-completado

Hace poco he ganado el privilegio de ["Editar Preguntas Y Respuestas"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

En la sección *¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?* dice:

- para clarificar el sentido de una **publciación** sin cambiarla

Allí, la palabra publicación está mal escrita. Me gustaría hacer esta corrección o a través de esta pregunta, hago esta observación.

Comment: ¡Qué buena observación! Tienes razón, está mal escrito, aunque no es un error de alto impacto esperemos que lo solucionen pronto :)

Comment: Corregido, gracias. En el futuro, para casos similares por favor publica una respuesta aquí: [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/sugerencias-de-mejora-en-las-traducciones)